# Does `gksudo` work for any GUI program?

Tags: gksu

I thought `gksudo` is what `sudo` is in terminal. I wanted to open SciTE eleveted and change some "protected" file, so I issue 'gksudo SciTE`, but nothing happens, SciTE isn't run at all - gksudo dialog shows, then I enter my password, but program doesn't start.

Is there some limitation which programs can be run under `gksudo`, or how do I run SciTE elevated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, there's always the old standby:

```
$ sudo su

# SciTE
```

Or maybe you could check the logs and find out if its failing for a reason?

Comment: It seems that problem is with the path: I have SciTE it in `~/.local/bin/SciTE` (which is in my PATH env set in `.bashrc`) which is not recognised when run `gksudo` for some reason. So running `gksudo ~/.local/bin/SciTE` works.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you have to use the *command* and not the name. Also remember that commands are case sensitive.

Comment: `SciTE` is command name for SciTE text editor if I understand you right

Comment: Ok. Highly unusual. :)

Comment: It builds itself by default with that name. Don't know about the executable in old version provided in Ubuntu repositories

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 14.04** when I installed SciTE it automatically created a link `/usr/bin/scite` to SciTE so either `gksu SciTE` or `gksu scite` works fine.

```
$ll /usr/bin/scite 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Oct 22  2013 /usr/bin/scite -> SciTE*
```